# Foreach in Yajra DataTable Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

I'm trying to put a foreach loop inside my datatable but it wont work,
P.S. if I remove the foreach everything works fine already,
attached here is my code

```
$Product = Product::query();
$colors   = Color::all();

return Datatables::eloquent($Product)

    ->addColumn('category_name', function($row) {

        $category = Category::select('name')->where('id', $row->category_id )->pluck('name')->toArray();
        return $category;

    })

    ->addColumn('add_color', function($row) {

        $return = 
            '<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="/procurement/add-product" style="max-width: 170px;">
            <input type="hidden" name= "product_id" value="' . $row->id . '">

            <div class="form-group">
            <select name="color_id" class="form-control" required autofocus>
                    '.foreach ($colors as $color){.' 
                    <option value="test">test</option>'.}.'
            </select>
            </div>';

        return $return;

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to perform foreach outside your return. and then you also need no `use` or import the `$color` variable inside your data table. something like this ..

```
$Product = Product::query();
$colors   = Color::all();

return Datatables::eloquent($Product)

->addColumn('category_name', function($row) {

    $category = Category::select('name')->where('id', $row->category_id )->pluck('name')->toArray();
    return $category;

})

->addColumn('add_color', function($row) use ($colors)  {
        $options = '';
        foreach ($colors as $color) {
            $options .= '<option value="test">$color</option>';
        }

    $return = 
        '<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="/procurement/add-product" style="max-width: 170px;">
        <input type="hidden" name= "product_id" value="' . $row->id . '">

        <div class="form-group">
        <select name="color_id" class="form-control" required autofocus>
        </select>
        </div>';

    return $return;

});
```

Answer (score 5):

That won't work, you're attaching a `foreach` into a `string`

What you may do is perform the `foreach` first to prepare the items you want to attach in that string.

E.g.,

```
<option>something</option>
<option>something more</option>
```

Before setting the `$return` do the `foreach`:

```
->addColumn('add_color', function($row) {

    $options = ''
    // here we prepare the options
    foreach ($colors as $color) {
        $options .= '<option value="test">$color</option>';
    }

    $return = 
       '<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="/procurement/add product" style="max-width: 170px;">
        <input type="hidden" name= "product_id" value="'.$row->id.'">

        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="color_id" class="form-control" required autofocus>' . $options . '</select>
        </div>';

    return $return;

})
```

Comment: wouldn't the options variable be useless because you'll just replace it on every loop?

Comment: @radren I used `.=` not `=`

Comment: ah sorry i did not see the .